# Adding google.maps.latLng objects to list causes [Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.latLng is not a function]

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I am doing an ajax call to the server to get latitude and longitude data and pushing them to a list containing google.maps.latLng coordinates. I'm doing some calculations because the matrix containing the data comes from a sparse matrix(will of course be rewritten because it's ugly so far). I know that my `tempLong` and `tempLat` values are correct, but I keep getting `[Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.latLng is not a function]` when i perform the ajax call. I suspect that this has do with the asynchronous call that ajax performs, but I'm not sure. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707303/adding-google-maps-latlng-to-an-array-within-a-loop) post and decided to put all my code in the `.done{}` function, but that does not help.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
function getMultipleArrays(){
var div = document.getElementById("map2");

$.get('getJSONObject', function(data) {

}).done(function(data){
    var minLat = data.minLat;
    var minLong = data.minLong;
    var m = data.m;
    var n = data.n;
    var val = data.val;
    var col = data.col;
    var row = data.row;
    var list =[];

    var minLatCoo= minLat*1000000;
    var minLongCoo= minLong*1000000;
    var i, j, k,zeroIndex;

    for(i=0; i<m;i++){
        zeroIndex=0;
        for(k=row[i]; k<row[i+1];k++){
            j= col[k];
            while(zeroIndex<j){
                zeroIndex++;
            }
            minLatCoo= minLat*1000000;
            minLongCoo= minLong*1000000;
            for(var l=val[k]; l>0;l--){
                minLatCoo+=zeroIndex;
                var tempLat = minLatCoo/1000000;
                minLongCoo+=i;
                var tempLong = minLongCoo/1000000;
                list.push(new google.maps.latLng(tempLong,tempLat));
                console.log(tempLong + " - " + tempLat);
            }
            zeroIndex++;
        }
    }
    console.log(list.length);
    console.log("DONE!");
    return list;
});}
```

The error occurs on the `list.push(new google.maps.latLng(tempLong,tempLat));` line. Any ideas why it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is LatLng, not latLng.  Javascript's case-sensitive; it should be

```
list.push(new google.maps.LatLng(tempLong,tempLat));
```

... not

```
list.push(new google.maps.latLng(tempLat, tempLong));
```

Also you do `new google.maps.latLng(tempLong,tempLat)` from which I inferred you've got your latitude and longitude mixed up.

See:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng